# Adding custom metadata to DataFrame schema using iceberg table format

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml, apache-spark-2.0

I'm adding custom metadata into the DataFrames schema in my PySpark application using [`StructField`'s metadata field](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-3569)

It worked fine when I wrote parquet files directly into s3.
The custom metadata was available when reading these parquet files as expected.

But it's not working using iceberg table format. There is no error, but the `df.schema.fields.metadata` is always empty.

Is there a way to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Solved by making sure the key is always 'comment'

For example:
{'comment': 'my_metadata_info_field'}